# How run a python program faster using GNU parallel?

Tags: python, gnu-parallel

I have a python program which can be executed using multiple threads, however, it fails (segmentation fault, core dumped) when using more than 1 thread.

What I was thinking of an alternate possibility to run script using GNU parallel. I am very new to this and have limited knowledge about the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is going to be very dependent on what your program does... are you just asking how to run a single python program using GNU parallel to make it run multiple?

Comment: So may be I am misunderstanding what GNU parallel does. Yes, I am asking how to run a single python program using GNU parallel. I am assuming that GNU parallel will help me distribute the computing part in a parallel fashion and that way it can help me execute it faster.

Comment: The best to achieve is to split the fasta file into multiple pieces and then use GNU parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have example.py and you want to run it N times. You can run the following

```
seq 10 | parallel -N0 --jobs 0 example.py
```

Breaking this down `seq 10` will cause 10 jobs to be run. The `-N0` flag tells us to ignore the input which would normally read in the input output by the `seq 10` command. `--jobs 0` will let as many run in parallel as you want.

As far as I know parallel doesn't let you say run this program X times with no input so you must abuse piping into the command with seq and then ignoring it with the -N0 flag.

Read this for further examples on commands: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Comment: I am sorry, the comment got posted without completion. Here it is

Comment: are you familiar with the linux terminal?

Comment: I am sorry, the comment got posted without completion. Here it is

How do you suggest running this script using parallel?


`date && time /opt/app/python-2.7.9/bin/python2.7 /opt/app/busco-master/scripts/run_BUSCO.py -i v.umbellata_final_assembly_master_datastore_index.maker.transcripts1000.fasta  -o v.umbellata_final_assembly_maker -l embryophyta_odb9/ -m genome --long -sp tomato -z --augustus_parameters='--progress=true'`

Comment: Just run the command with double quotes around it. I'm not going to help any beyond that you will need to figure some of it out yourself or post a new question.

Comment: Additionally if your intent was how to run this specific command from the beginning you will get better results on this site if you post the full context in your question.

Comment: Sure, I will definitely figure out something. Thanks for the help! much appreciated. The reason why I did not post the complete command was because I thought that would be confusing (rather would not make any sense to non-bioinformatician). That is, it is hard to explain the parameters here. I am really sorry if that was a mistake. Thanks once again

Comment: yep no problem, if the above answers your original questions please accept it. If not try updating the original question so myself or someone else can get you the answer you are looking for.